# What is the format of this string 2016-06-17 01:34:50.000 PM

Tags: simpledateformat

2016-06-17 01:34:50.000 PM

What format is this?
However, it gives unparsable date exception.

Code :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss.SSSZ a", Locale.ENGLISH);

   try {
         date = format.parse("2016-06-17 01:34:50.000 PM");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified that the date should contain a timezone with the "Z" but your date string doesn't have one. Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss.SSS a", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

or add a timezone to the string you are trying to parse.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)